# Toggle link background color

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```js
$("li").click(function() {
  $("li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
})
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

If you click one link twice, the background color should disappear. Unfortunately, it does not work.

Can somebody help me please? Would be very happy!

Love.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the first step removes the class on all `<li>` , including the current one if applicable. Then if it was already removed from current one `toggLeClass()` will add it back.

Simple fix is use `not()` for the removal and exclude the current `<li>`

```js
$("li").click(function() {
  $("li").not(this).removeClass("active");
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
})
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Soooo smart! Thaaankssss

Comment: Could also do `$(this).siblings('.active').removeClass('active')` which also excludes the current one

Answer (score 0):

add not this select to the li remove class

```js
$("li").click(function() {
  $("li").not(this).removeClass("active");
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
})
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thaaaaaankssss!